# Why there is a silver top and left border when I set box-shadow and border-radius on input?

Tags: html, css, border, box-shadow

When I set box-shadow and border-radius on input there appears a border as

[image]

How to remove it?

```
<input class="input-time py-2" type="time" value="00:00"></input>
```

```
.input-time {
    width: 90%;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px rgba(50, 0, 234, 0.3);
    border-radius: 40px;
}
```

Comment: That is the default style of input in browsers. It applies a default `border`. Use `border: none` to remove it.

Comment: Browser default. Set your own border ex: `border: solid 1px #dbdbdb;`

Comment: you're welcome, don't hesitate to thumbs up!